# How to define asset dependency in a gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I'm wondering if there is a way to define a gem dependency "bound" to a bundler group.

I assume that `add_development_dependency` acts somehow like `gem "foo", group: [:test, :development]`

So if I make a gem which depends on jquery (bad example, I know) for example should I add this dependency? My thoughts on that:

- **normal dependency**: The gem is only needed on asset compiling stages but a normal dependency would get installed even if not needed
- **development dependency**: would at least indicate what is needed but it does not solve the actual problem
- **no dependency**: the user has to take care

What can or should I do? I know that the asset pipeline is very rails related but is there a way of using bundler groups for gem dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Though uncommon of a need, you can always write ruby eval code in the `Gemfile` itself.

This is not a bad place for it, since this is the 'domain' of `rubygems` and `Bundler` - thus you can utilize their APIs to validate gem versions, if they've loaded — as well as the existence of your target groups.

You could then define these target groups as part of your gem's API, and document it for other engineers